# 'append' option in Net::SFTP::Foreign->get() is not working as expected

Tags: perl, file, sftp

I am copying the file from remote machine to the local and this operation to be perform everyday once. In case of append of content in the remote file content, i will just copy the appended content to local file(as it is already exists at local machine). I am using Net::SFTP::Foreign module from CPAN, but seems like it is copying the full file in case of append(which is not expected).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my $file = '/home/user/temp/test.txt';
my $destination = '/home/user/dest.txt';

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
   host      => 'localhost',           # using localhost for destination and source
   more      => [ -o => 'Compression yes', '-v' ]
);

$sftp->get( $file, $destination, copy_perm => 1, append => 1 );

if($sftp->error) {
  print "get operation failed for $file : " . $sftp->error . "\n";
}
```

I checked the Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm module for get() implementation and found below code snippet in case of append -

```
my $flags = Fcntl::O_CREAT|Fcntl::O_WRONLY;
$flags |= Fcntl::O_APPEND if $append;
$lstart = sysseek($fh, 0, 1) if $append;
```

In case of append,$lstart contains the 0 only, which is beginning of the file. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Looks like that _should_ be `$lstart = sysseek($fh, 0, **2**) if $append;`, as I _think_ the code there is meant to use `SEEK_END` (usually defined as 2) for the `lseek(2)` call, not `SEEK_CUR` (usually defined as 1).

Comment: @Castaglia: yes, `Net::SFTP::Foreign`, is depending on the OS seeking to the end of file because of `O_APPEND`, but that is implementation dependent. POSIX only guarantees the seek before any write operation.

Comment: The bug is now fixed on the development version at https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-SFTP-Foreign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you comments, actually i found the reason why it was not working properly. It was keep overwriting the local file with remote one.
But when i use below code :

```
$sftp->get(
    $file,
    '/home/user/test.log',
    append    => 1,
    overwrite => 0,
);
```

Now it won't overwrite the file, but append the whole file to the local file.
While i wanted to just append the text which is added to the remote file rather than the whole file.
This feature does not support by the Net::SFTP::Foreign.

Comment: oh, then,[`resume`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#resume-1-auto) is what you are looking for!

Comment: So, will below code work fine for me -
$sftp->get(
    $file,
    '/home/user/test.log',
    append    => 1,
    overwrite => 0,
    resume => 1
);

Or resume should not be used with append/overwrite?

Comment: just `$sftp->get($file, '/home/user/test.log', resume => 1);`

Comment: BTW, if you have full SSH access to the remote machine, a more robust solution for file synchronization is `rsync`.  Check the [`rsync_get`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#ssh-rsync_get-opts-remote1-remote2-...-local_dir_or_file) method provided by [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH).